# How does Jave prevent concurrent class initializing from happening?

Tags: java, class, jvm

A java class is initialized only once per one JVM, when the class is loaded first. And I think more than one thread can try to load the same class concurrently. How does a JVM handle the contention of this? Is there any mechanism to prevent it from happening, like lock?

Comment: `A java class is initialized only once per one jvm` - that is not true. Correct statement should be `A java class is initialized only once per classloader`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the following statement is not accurate:

> A java class is initialized only once per one jvm

A Java class is initialized once per **classloader**. A JVM instance may very well have several classloaders, each one loading the same class separately.

And to answer the question - yes, the classloader must take a lock while loading the class. If, e.g., you take a look at OpenJDK 9's implementation of `java.lang.ClassLoader`, loading a class will eventually boil down to the following method (comment added to emphasize the locking):

```
final Class<?> loadClass(Module module, String name) {
    synchronized (getClassLoadingLock(name)) { // Note the locking here!
        // First, check if the class has already been loaded
        Class<?> c = findLoadedClass(name);
        if (c == null) {
            c = findClass(module.getName(), name);
        }
        if (c != null && c.getModule() == module) {
            return c;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From a JVM’s perspective, “several classloaders, each one loading the same class separately” are just several class loaders defining *different* classes, even if they may have the same name or even the same byte code. Therefore, the statement “A java class is initialized only once per one jvm” is correct and accurate. Besides that, the cited code is only implementing *loading* of the class, not the *initialization*. Ensuring that initialization happens only once is still left to the JVM.